# Problemas de conexão

Tags: php, mysqli

Ao enviar o form para cadastrar o email digitado no campo ele deveria simplesmente cadastrar na base de dados, mas ele não cadastra, como posso resolver?

```
<?php    
    $conect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root@localhost','') or die ("erro de conecção");
    $banco = mysqli_select_db($conect,'oserpoeta');
    var_dump($banco)
?>
```

**Página pega dados**

```
<?php     
    include = 'cad_&else.php';

    //Cadastra os dados
    $email = $_POST ["email"];    
    $link = "INSERT INTO 'newllester' ('email') VALUES ('$email')";    
    $qur = mysqli_query($link,'$sql')or die('erro:'.mysqli_error ());    
    header("location: http://serpoeta.localhost/serpoeta/")    
?>
```

Comment: 1. Leia a documentação da função [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php); 2. Qual o retorno de `var_dump($banco)`? 3. Não coloque aspas simples no nome da tabela ou nome das colunas - se quiser evitar conflito, use crases; 4. Leia a documentação da função [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) e reveja a ordem dos parâmetros; 5. O que deveria ser a variável `$sql` que utilizou em `mysqli_query`?

Comment: Não vai aspas simples no nome da tabela. Não coloque aspas simples em variáveis como => `'$sql')or die(...);`

Comment: Melhorando uma linha: `$conect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root@localhost','','oserpoeta') or die ("erro de conecção");`
Você pode já setar o banco junto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `mysqli` você não precisa de usar `mysqli_select_db`, basta usar o seguinte código

```
$conect = mysqli_connect('servidor','nome_utilizador','palavra_pass', 'nome_da_db') or die ("erro de conecção");


$link = "INSERT INTO 'newllester' ('email') VALUES ('$email')";

$qur = mysqli_query($link,'$sql')or die('erro:'.mysqli_error ());
```

Além disso, o código acima está mal formulado. Onde você diz a query, o primeiro dado deve ser a ligação à base de dados, ou seja

```
$qur = mysqli_query($conect, $link)or die('erro:'.mysqli_error ());
```